# How to visualise the relative contribution of 3 parameters in a single plot/map?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `dataframe` that contains a relative contribution of 3 parameters (please see below to get the reproducible `dataframe`). The contributions from each parameter add to 1. I want to make a single `ggplot2` plot (map) where I can visualise which parameter contributes how much.

What I have tried so far:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(df, ggplot2::aes(x, y, fill = sum)) +
        ggplot2::geom_tile() +
        ggplot2::scale_fill_viridis_c() +
        ggplot2::coord_quickmap() +
        ggplot2::facet_grid(parameter~.)
```

which produces:

[image]

As you can see, it is not so informative about how much exactly each parameter contributes. How can I visualise these data in a single plot with detailed information about the contribution value of each parameter?

**Reproducible data:**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(parameter = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", 
"a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", 
"b", "b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", 
"c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"
), x = c(-73.5, -72.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, 
-64.5, -63.5, -73.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, 
-70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, 
-73.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -67.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -71.5, -70.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -74.5, 
-71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -72.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -71.5, -70.5, 
-69.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -69.5, -73.5, -72.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -64.5, -63.5, -73.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, 
-65.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -71.5, -70.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -73.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-67.5, -74.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-67.5, -66.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -71.5, 
-70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -74.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -72.5, -71.5, 
-70.5, -69.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -69.5, 
-73.5, -72.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -64.5, 
-63.5, -73.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -70.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -65.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, 
-66.5, -65.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -73.5, 
-71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, 
-67.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -66.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-68.5, -67.5, -74.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -68.5, -74.5, -71.5, 
-70.5, -69.5, -72.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, -71.5, -70.5, -69.5, 
-69.5, -68.5, -67.5, -69.5), y = c(-40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, 
-40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, 
-41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, 
-42.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -44.5, -44.5, 
-44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, 
-45.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, 
-47.5, -47.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -49.5, -49.5, 
-49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.5, -50.5, -50.5, -50.5, -51.5, -51.5, 
-51.5, -51.5, -52.5, -52.5, -52.5, -53.5, -53.5, -54.5, -55.5, 
-40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, 
-40.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -42.5, 
-42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, 
-43.5, -43.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -45.5, 
-45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, 
-46.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, 
-48.5, -48.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, -50.5, -50.5, 
-50.5, -50.5, -51.5, -51.5, -51.5, -51.5, -52.5, -52.5, -52.5, 
-53.5, -53.5, -54.5, -55.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, 
-40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -40.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -41.5, 
-41.5, -41.5, -41.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, -42.5, 
-43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -43.5, -44.5, -44.5, -44.5, 
-44.5, -44.5, -44.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, -45.5, 
-46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -46.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, -47.5, 
-47.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -48.5, -49.5, -49.5, -49.5, 
-49.5, -49.5, -50.5, -50.5, -50.5, -50.5, -51.5, -51.5, -51.5, 
-51.5, -52.5, -52.5, -52.5, -53.5, -53.5, -54.5, -55.5), sum = c(0, 
9.46581738186483e-05, 0.00696497150559271, 0.0137849902303819, 
0.00643740569455534, 0.00199816358740475, 0, 0, 0, 5.06412179534512e-05, 
0, 0.0398551254689963, 0.0310856391742892, 0.0195084547186265, 
0.00122115866765995, 0.000262981842424393, 0.000728947548683327, 
0.0180714589486645, 0.0217375647896753, 0.0302549061176794, 0.0121843041040885, 
0.000681282606889494, 4.35093747206288e-05, 0.0529538781527676, 
0.0273285713315873, 0.0110374092101145, 0.00537239572379284, 
0.00472400342189244, 0.00147365976111469, 0.0259683795649571, 
0.0463436806229692, 0.0267969428070688, 0.020294577628928, 0.00821922974468169, 
0.00233230625628307, 0.00387696973516025, 0.0514313688652839, 
0.0645759934429092, 0.0239569529899347, 0.027534701081013, 0.00534849512202001, 
0.00128844338962426, 0.0426685507779651, 0.0284580643386483, 
0.00971006844234354, 0.00420984206165692, 0.053985050339934, 
0.0583984918343995, 0.0172826529268439, 0.0121423976240239, 0.00547793750320507, 
0.0585686295112969, 0.0340311779773938, 0.0311015513254945, 0.0200707300297805, 
0.00957150788475225, 0.00361466936278744, 0.0527542952718002, 
0.0282832440286811, 0.0177806525711058, 0.00560265899046886, 
0.0024828404080448, 0.0544720394354926, 0.0186537760879564, 0.0192277515814812, 
0.00863003055518693, 0.0249790371500353, 0.015538215176512, 0.0348873548749255, 
0.0206759639364579, 0.0139234477581141, 0.0205576837132205, 0.0404500818602786, 
0.00653946544041233, 0.0223237332992225, 0.0075707047472664, 
0.55973614025667, 0.5970202227548, 0.563477650463872, 0.513046833650201, 
0.633380146860311, 0.653109185283395, 0.704255523998351, 0.596896242072055, 
0.520747918302268, 0.526828987547501, 0.592212337251761, 0.590540320713732, 
0.480335397306457, 0.631079557708342, 0.6667829974047, 0.64403959660305, 
0.591513715061531, 0.572154253402492, 0.506765134717002, 0.664156380590966, 
0.67826734460919, 0.649022944246854, 0.651215734871819, 0.488798113249405, 
0.458045272783363, 0.693687132763554, 0.700613923064021, 0.751238707050007, 
0.712027653396489, 0.532585134221796, 0.476479299998232, 0.490080331523103, 
0.705251451061017, 0.735714385706559, 0.607922959590343, 0.613134683073939, 
0.487692533841504, 0.548015750900016, 0.509952441369207, 0.74439726199284, 
0.690392471171559, 0.588966236272818, 0.659362140614673, 0.646180042358758, 
0.631416450548492, 0.585094155496678, 0.604202144807992, 0.647823791170224, 
0.599329297279972, 0.725121813884829, 0.650627029395497, 0.542872019089378, 
0.65883061118346, 0.66671626220512, 0.639294598531845, 0.622768680020925, 
0.479380596605895, 0.580708446644663, 0.579879141984736, 0.617496249696512, 
0.483541553869077, 0.474759409900493, 0.42759500296535, 0.444245282360467, 
0.491426697536639, 0.543068445843191, 0.354391820625675, 0.285449114670143, 
0.230667732146117, 0.545516189964805, 0.549909364018411, 0.518094993608081, 
0.580561287344482, 0.591327797599958, 0.52693632685116, 0.64278661995468, 
0.44026385974333, 0.402885119071382, 0.429557378030536, 0.473168176119417, 
0.360182447445134, 0.3448926511292, 0.295744476001649, 0.403103757927945, 
0.479252081697732, 0.473120371234546, 0.407787662748239, 0.369604553817271, 
0.488578963519254, 0.349411987573031, 0.33199584392764, 0.355697421554526, 
0.407757337389786, 0.409774287648843, 0.471497300493323, 0.305588713291354, 
0.309548351286721, 0.350295773146257, 0.34874075575346, 0.458248008597827, 
0.514626155885049, 0.295275458026332, 0.294013681212186, 0.244037289528101, 
0.286498686842396, 0.441446486213247, 0.477177019378799, 0.483122725669829, 
0.274453971310055, 0.256066384548759, 0.389744734153374, 0.3829883471909, 
0.460876097293212, 0.387408255657075, 0.466090605640859, 0.228068036926147, 
0.304259033706421, 0.409745320337558, 0.297969308607362, 0.325361893302593, 
0.358873481009164, 0.410696002441665, 0.341812804852074, 0.293777716995377, 
0.383388049793184, 0.262735788491147, 0.343895033101298, 0.398559351399325, 
0.307138210839147, 0.302182186469385, 0.340634671438375, 0.367659812094323, 
0.517004734031317, 0.366537258083536, 0.391837613986583, 0.364723097732382, 
0.510855787140454, 0.522757749691462, 0.517932957599158, 0.537100941551577, 
0.48934555088188, 0.448301523601622, 0.62062914222429, 0.699012670153345, 
0.734444912978957, 0.433807846098737, 0.436167188223475, 0.461347322678698, 
0.37898863079524, 0.40213273695963, 0.450739939849617, 0.349642675298054
)), row.names = c(NA, -228L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is via color mixing. You assign a, b and c to red, green and blue, and calculate the RGB colour that represents the weighting of a,b and c.

For example, in your data there is very little contribution from parameter a, so we would expect most cells to be somewhere between green and blue:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from = sum) %>%
  mutate(col = rgb(a, b, c)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color = parameter), data = df) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue')) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10, shape = 15))) +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

If we were to multiply `a` by 15, we get a better idea of how such a plot might look in general (though unlike the plot above, this is *not* representative of your data - purely for illustration)

[image]

We get a very similar (though less accurate) result with somewhat less effort by mapping the fill color to `parameter` and the alpha aesthetic to `sum` with `scale_alpha_identity`

```r
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = parameter, alpha = sum), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red', 'green', 'blue')) +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

An alternative is to use `geom_hextri` as defined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76709204/using-hexbins-to-show-proportion-of-categorical-variables-like-in-hextri/76750172#76750172)

```r
df %>%
  uncount(weights = round(sum * 10)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y, fill = parameter, group = parameter)) +
  geom_hextri(linewidth = 0.3, bins = 13, color = 'gray50') +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  scale_alpha_identity() +
  theme_minimal() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-76, -62)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-57, -39)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1)
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

To add a color key to the legend you might need to stitch a ternary plot onto the side using patchwork:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggtern)

main_plot <- df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = parameter, values_from = sum) %>%
  mutate(col = rgb(a, b, c)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(aes(fill = col), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_equal() +
  theme_minimal()

df2 <- expand.grid(a = seq(0, 1, 0.01), b = seq(0, 1, 0.01), c = seq(0, 1, 0.01))
df2 <- df2[rowSums(df2) == 1,]
df2$rgb <- rgb(df2$a, df2$b, df2$c)

legend_plot <- ggtern(df2, aes(a, b, z = c, color = rgb)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity() +
  scale_L_continuous(labels = function(x) character(length(x))) +
  ggtitle("Relative values") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        axis.text = element_blank())

library(patchwork)

main_plot + 
  wrap_elements(ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(legend_plot))) +
  plot_layout(design = "AAAA#
                        AAAAB
                        AAAA#")
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice approach, thanks a lot! But, is dividing by `sum(sum)` necessary? Bc, as I mentioned in the post, relative contributions add to 1. Second, would you please explain what do we want to do with the `geom_point` layer? In this small example, it seems to work fine, but when I use my original data (much larger area) it seems to add really large 'point-like' objects to the plot and messes things up a bit :)

Comment: @bird the geom_point layer is only added so that we can have a legend. It's possible to change it so the points are invisible. You're right about the `sum` part - probably best with a pivot here. I'll add an update when I get a chance

Comment: Is there a way to add a legend that would show more detailed 'color value', like a ternary plot? I think it would be more useful if we can see what is red, green and blue, but also what is between blue and red etc.

Comment: @bird probably the best way is just sticking an appropriate ternary plot on the side. See my update.