# Highlight particular hex bins with geom_hex and alter the linewidths of highlighted bins

Tags: r, ggplot2

I previously asked a [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76685323/highlight-particular-hex-bins-with-geom-hex), asking how to highlight particular bins in a hexbin plot.
Now I want to adjust the linewidth of the bins being highlighted. However, I cannot get the two hexbin geoms to align. Previous answers suggested that setting group = 1 in the aes would fix the problem, but this didnt work for me.

Here is some code showing the hexbin plot, and the misaligned overlayed hexbins. I want the two geoms to align so that the highlighted hexbins from stat_summary_hex overlay the geom_hex's

```
n = 1000

df = data.frame(x = rnorm(n), 
                y = rnorm(n),
                group = sample(0:1, n, prob = c(0.9, 0.1), replace = TRUE))
df$sums[df$group == 1] = runif(sum(df$group == 1), min = 0.5, max = 2)

pp = ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group)) +
  geom_hex() +
  stat_summary_hex(aes(
    z = sums,
    linewidth = after_stat(value),
    group = 1
  ), fun = ~ + sum(.x), col = "gold", fill = NA)  + 
  scale_linewidth(range = c(0.1, 1))
pp
```

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that your `sums` column has only missings for the `0` group. Hence, these observations get dropped in `stat_summary_hex` (you should get a warning about that)  and you end up with a different binning. To fix that I recode the `sums` variable for the `0` group as `-999`. In `stat_summary_hex` i compute the sum only for the non-negative aka group 1 values.

Additionally, to me it was not clear why you map `group` on the `group` aes which also results in overlapping bins, i.e. each group gets treated separately. Hence I dropped it and of course also the `group=1` which does not make sense.

Note: As the 0 group now gets assigned a value of 0 I have set the minimum for the linewidth range to `0`.

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(123)

df$sums[is.na(df$sums)] <- -999

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_hex() +
  stat_summary_hex(aes(
    z = sums,
    linewidth = after_stat(value),
  ), fun = ~ sum(.x[.x > 0]), col = "gold", fill = NA) +
  scale_linewidth(range = c(0, 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank-you again Stefan. The NA's were this missing problem for both the example and my real data. However, this solution in my real data (not in the example) now changes the scale of the fill to the linewidth value and I have no idea why. I put an example with the real data in this gist:
https://gist.github.com/SamPassmore/be1a4160c18049cae0ec3092f082c0ae